# I am getting Access blocked error while trying to get athentication code which i will use to get refresh token?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

here is what is tried
I changed the status of O Auth Consent screen from testing to publish and the app scope is external then i created the O Auth client Id token and then i tried this code but this is giving error when i try to authenticate to the app.

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'client.json'

REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')
print(f'Please go to this URL to authorize the application: {auth_url}')
auth_code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')
flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
creds = flow.credentials
print(f'Access token: {creds.token}')
print(f'Refresh token: {creds.refresh_token}')
```

Can you spot how to do it in python and solve this error.

Comment: It will help if you [edit] the question to include the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, this was discontinued.

You would have better luck following the official [QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)

This sample will use  creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0) to open the consent screen for you rather then asking you to click a link which will probably return a 404 error because you don't have a local web server running.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```